# react native webview error, com.reactnativecommunity.webview.events does not exist

Tags: react-native, android-webview

I am trying to use https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview.

I get this error when I try and `react-native run-android`, any ideas how I can use webview?

**\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:54: error: package com.reactnativecommunity.webview.events does not exist**

Using:

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.57.1

error in full:

> Task :react-native-webview:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>   C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:54: error: package com.reactnativecommunity.webview.events does not exist
>   import com.reactnativecommunity.webview.events.TopLoadingErrorEvent;
>                                                 ^
>   C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:55: error: package com.reactnativecommunity.webview.events does not exist
>   import com.reactnativecommunity.webview.events.TopLoadingFinishEvent;
>                                                 ^
>   C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:56: error: package com.reactnativecommunity.webview.events does not exist
>   import com.reactnativecommunity.webview.events.TopLoadingProgressEvent;
>                                                 ^
>   C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:57: error: package com.reactnativecommunity.webview.events does not exist
>   import com.reactnativecommunity.webview.events.TopLoadingStartEvent;
>                                                 ^
>   C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:58: error: package com.reactnativecommunity.webview.events does not exist
>   import com.reactnativecommunity.webview.events.TopMessageEvent;
>                                                 ^
>   C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:59: error: package com.reactnativecommunity.webview.events does not exist
>   import com.reactnativecommunity.webview.events.TopShouldStartLoadWithRequestEvent;
>                                                 ^
>   C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:455: error: cannot find symbol
>       export.put(TopLoadingProgressEvent.EVENT_NAME, MapBuilder.of("registrationName", "onLoadingProgress"));
>                  ^
>     symbol:   variable TopLoadingProgressEvent
>     location: class RNCWebViewManager
>   C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:456: error: cannot find symbol
>       export.put(TopShouldStartLoadWithRequestEvent.EVENT_NAME, MapBuilder.of("registrationName", "onShouldStartLoadWithRequest"));
>                  ^
>     symbol:   variable TopShouldStartLoadWithRequestEvent
>     location: class RNCWebViewManager
>   C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:457: error: method getJSEventName in enum ScrollEventType cannot be applied to given types;
>       export.put(ScrollEventType.getJSEventName(ScrollEventType.SCROLL), MapBuilder.of("registrationName", "onScroll"));
>                                 ^
>     required: no arguments
>     found: ScrollEventType
>     reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
>   C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:732: error: cannot find symbol
>           new TopLoadingProgressEvent(
>               ^
>     symbol:   class TopLoadingProgressEvent
>     location: class RNCWebChromeClient
>   C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:617: error: cannot find symbol
>           new TopLoadingStartEvent(
>               ^
>     symbol:   class TopLoadingStartEvent
>     location: class RNCWebViewClient
>   C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:626: error: cannot find symbol
>           new TopShouldStartLoadWithRequestEvent(
>               ^
>     symbol:   class TopShouldStartLoadWithRequestEvent
>     location: class RNCWebViewClient
>   C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:659: error: cannot find symbol
>           new TopLoadingErrorEvent(webView.getId(), eventData));
>               ^
>     symbol:   class TopLoadingErrorEvent
>     location: class RNCWebViewClient
>   C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:665: error: cannot find symbol
>           new TopLoadingFinishEvent(
>               ^
>     symbol:   class TopLoadingFinishEvent
>     location: class RNCWebViewClient
>   C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:901: error: cannot find symbol
>         dispatchEvent(this, new TopMessageEvent(this.getId(), message));
>                                 ^
>     symbol:   class TopMessageEvent
>     location: class RNCWebView
>   Note: C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   Note: C:\Users\Matt\sites\tcapp\node_modules\react-native-webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
>   15 errors
>
> Task :react-native-webview:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Answer (score 1):

This issue happened to me

i had these versions of react-native and `react-native-webview` version

```
 "react-native-webview": "^5.12.1"

{
   "react": "16.8.3",
   "react-native": "0.59.9",
   "react-native-webview": "^5.12.1",
   ...
}
```

Everything was fine for my previous version of project nothing happned with this version.

After updating android-studio and upgrade the gradle, i freshly build and run the same project (after i clone the same project from my github repo.). This issue occured, then i put and checked each new version (above 5.12.1) of `react-native-webview`. Finally, it matched, fixed the error and successfully build the app with this version.

```
"react-native-webview": "^7.5.2"

{
   "react": "16.8.3",
   "react-native": "0.59.9",
   "react-native-webview": "^7.5.2",
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. click node_modules folder
2. delete react-native-webview folder

**install latest one**  `npm i react-native-webview`